# Is Fedora 34 configured for IPv4 link-local addresses?

Tags: fedora, routing, ipv4

[This page](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1357/_index.html), linked from the `avahi-autoipd` man page says:

> Most modern Linux distributions already include full IPv4 link-local support

However, if I look at the routing table on my Fedora 34 machine, I only see these three routes:

```
default via 10.180.64.1 dev wlo1 proto dhcp metric 600 
10.180.64.0/22 dev wlo1 proto kernel scope link src 10.180.66.146 metric 600 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown
```

By my understanding, the first line means packets with an IPv4LL destination (169.254.x.x) will be sent to the router rather than directly to their destination.

This would mean that the packet would only be delivered if the router was aware of IPv4LL addresses, which I don't think is true of all routers.

Does Fedora actually handle IPv4LL addresses out of the box? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux distributions stopped doing IPv4ALL by default.

> [network-manager: no longer falls back to link-local ipv4](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=519309) 
> Date: Wed, 11 Mar 2009 19:42:01 UTC
>
> since the upgrade to 0.7, it seems that [NetworkManager] doesn't fall back to
> link-local ipv4 in case dhcp times out, and instead goes into
> 'disconnected' state. ...

> [Re: DHCP fall back to link-local? (IPv4)](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/networkmanager-list/2009-April/msg00102.html) 
> Date: Thu, 16 Apr 2009 11:53:01 -0400
>
> ... you've just added about 45
> seconds of latency to the connection
>
> ... **if you know you want zeroconf, use zeroconf, don't use DHCP**
>
> ... fallback to zeroconf is
> simply confusing for a ton of users (which is why that behavior was
> removed in the first place)

My Fedora Workstation system mentions "Link-Local Only", as an alternative option to DHCP, under the IPv4 tab.  I haven't tried it, so I give no promises about whether it works at all :-).

Note your link was to an Apple page, that was last updated in 2005. The Apple page also has a note at the top, saying that it is not updated any more.